# Can I enlarge a RAID partition?

Tags: linux, partition, opensuse, raid, mdadm

I have an OpenSUSE 42.3 system with a RAID5 (mdadm) made out of four discs (2 2TB and 2 3TB). I'm growing the RAID by replacing the 2TB discs with larger ones. The 3TB discs have only 2TB partitions on them (fdisk reports 1.8TB); the rest of the discs is not allocated.

Can I somehow *enlarge* the 2TB partitions *in-situ* or must I resilver the discs (remove them from the array, partition as 3TB and re-add)?

Comment: [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/459640/207992) suggests `mdadm --grow --size max <md device>`

Comment: @NickODell: "I replaced 2x160GB with 2x500GB drives" - sounds like resilvering.

Comment: `parted -l`, `mdadm --examine` for each disk involved? Usually this "just works" but some corner cases exist (e.g. if the metadata is at the end of partition and then you change the partition size).